# Kill all user sessions after password change on Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, warden

When a User updates their password, I want to invalidate all their sessions (like on the phone or another browser) and give out a single new session to the current device. 
It seems to work if I just call 
`sign_out @user; sign_in @user`, it seems to work.

However, I cannot find documentation supporting this claim, apart from the actual implementation of the Devise#sign_out and Warden#logout methods.

Is there a cleaner or better documented solution?

Thank you!